# Модели в Джанго

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-orm

Как правильно расширить модель?

Предположим есть модели: Матч, Игрок, Команда.
Необходимо вывести в шаблон все матчи с командами и составом игроков. Модель "Матч" автоматически читает по внешнему ключу модели Команд и добавляет в QuerySet.

Как добавить туда еще и игроков по командам (дома/гости)? 
Наверняка ведь не требуется при передаче в шаблон отдельно строить выборку по Игрокам с фильтром по идентификатору матча.

Answer (score 0):

Если у модели "Команда" есть отношение многое-ко-многим к модели "Игрок", задачу можно решить, используя шаблоны:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for match in matches %}
  {{match}}
  <br>
  {% for player in match.home.players.all %}
    <br> игроок:
    {{player}}
  {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Так понимаю, что вы пишите нечто футбольное на Django? Дело в том, что я давно занимаюсь своим проектом в качестве хобби. Он посвящён дворовой лиге моего города. Если вам будет интересно - могли бы вместе поработать с джангой и сделать классный проект в портфолио!

Comment: Михаил, спасибо за ответ! Естественно, у Команды и Игрока отношение 1 ко многим, потому что один игрок не может числиться в других командах. Мой проект связан с американским спортом, это тоже хобби. Спасибо за предложение, но я пока поработаю в своем темпе.

Comment: Пока задачу решил добавив во view вычитывание команд, по сути это равносильно тому, что вы написали. Но это будет замедлять отклик, так как будет делать несколько запросов в БД. Придется кэшировать итоговый рендер в redis.